# Mathematica not seeing my environment/system variables

Tags: system-variables

I'm trying to access my environment variables in Mathematica, but I get a Failed result every time. For example:

```
$ echo $USER
jlconlin
```

but in Mathematica I do:

```
Environment["User"]     
(* $Failed *)
```

Is there a preference that I need to set? Is my Mathematica installation messed up? Please advise.

Comment: Please try `GetEnvironment[]`

Comment: As @halirutan exposed, I didn't capitalize correctly. Now what do I do when I'm expecting an environment variable, but don't see it in Mathematica when I use `GetEnvironment`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your environment variable is all upper-case!

```
Environment["USER"]
```

If you have capitalized your variable correctly and you still don't see it in *Mathematica*, then this is a problem of your window environment. *Mathematica* is a graphical program which doesn't get the same environment as you have in a terminal.

First you should try to start *Mathematica* from the very same terminal that knows about your variable. If this works, then you need to change the environment when you start *Mathematica* from an icon.

This procedure is different for every operating system. In Linux, you use something like this in your icon launcher:

```
env WEIRD=1 /usr/local/bin/Mathematica
```

and you will have `WEIRD` in your running *Mathematica*.

In OSX, you use `launchctl` for this.

Comment: Of course this is the answer. Now what do I do if I'm expecting a variable (i.e., I can see it in bash) but `Environment` doesn't see it. (I double checked that I have the right capitalization!)

Comment: @Jeremy See my update.